# Time Scaling in Nonlinear Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

Take the following nonlinear differential equations
$$
A_1 \ddot x_1(t) + B \dot x_1(t) + C x_1(t) = f(x_1) \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
A_2 \ddot x_2(t) + B \dot x_2(t) + C x_2(t) = f(x_2) \tag{2}
$$
with
$$
x_1(t=0) = x_2(t=0) = x_0\\
\dot x_1(t=0) = \dot x_2(t=0) =0.
$$
Here, $B$, $C$ and $f(.)$ are equal for both equations. I simulated different examples for function $f(.)$ such as $sin(.)$, $exp(.)$, $\sqrt{.}$ and different combinations of nonlinear operations, and it always holds
$$
x_1(t) = x_2(\sqrt{A_2/A_1}t). \tag{3}
$$
Please note that $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ are obtained via numerical methods. In other word, due to the unknown nature of $f(.)$, no analytical solution is available.

**Question** When $f(x) = 0$, $(1)$ and $(2)$ will become homogeneous linear differential equations, for which $(3)$ is easily explainable. How can I explain $(3)$ when we are dealing with an unknown function of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce the function $g:x\mapsto C x - f(x)$ so that the differential equations read
$$
A_i \ddot x_i + B\dot x_i + g(x_i) = 0 , \qquad i\in \lbrace 1,2\rbrace .
$$
Now, let us substitute $x_1(t) = x_2(\tau)$ with $\tau = \alpha t$ and $\alpha = \sqrt{A_2/A_1}$ in the differential equation for $i=1$. By using the chain rule, we have
$\dot x_1(t) = \alpha \dot x_2(\tau)$ and $\ddot x_1(t) = \alpha^2 \ddot x_2(\tau)$.
Thus, by using the other differential equation ($i=2$), we have
\begin{aligned}
A_1 \ddot x_1(t) + B \dot x_1(t) + g(x_1(t)) &= A_1\alpha^2 \ddot x_2(\tau) + B\alpha \dot x_2(\tau) + g(x_2(\tau)) \\
&= A_2 \ddot x_2(\tau) + B\alpha \dot x_2(\tau) + g(x_2(\tau)) \\
&= B(\alpha-1) \dot x_2(\tau) \neq 0
\end{aligned}
in general.
Therefore, your claim is wrong for non-constant solutions unless $B=0$ or $A_1=A_2$.

Answer (score 0):

The claim will hold if anytime you change $A_1$ to $A_2$, you also change $B_1$ to $B_2$ as follows
$$
B_2 = B_1 \sqrt{A_2 / A_1}.
$$